# DDD - Credentials to external contexts

Tags: api, domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

My application automates some actions on an external system on behalf of the user. Let's call this context of my application Inventory BC.

Since that is one of the main characteristics of my application it is modeled as a domain service and implemented with an anticorruption layer. All great so far.

Also, the user might have a couple different accounts on that external system that my application will handle for them. So I have a separate bounded context where I keep the user details and their account ids from the external system. Let's say Identity BC.

Now, the anticorruption layer of Inventory BC needs the external system account id and credentials. The account id is part of Inventory BC to separate the external accounts and operations that can't be made across those external accounts. But I'm not sure where I should store the credentials and how to retrieve them from the Inventory ACL.

Should I keep the credentials along their account ids in the Identity BC? Then I guess I could make an application service to return the credentials for a given account id and call it from the Inventory ACL.

Or is there a better practice?

**Edit1:** Also, if I was to fold all my contexts into one, what would be appropriate?

**Edit2:** On my domain service for the external system, should credentials be part of the method params? Or should I continue with a solution involving the credentials at the ACL level?

Answer (score 1):

It's all a bit blurry, but having the external system credentials in the Identity BC alongside your system's user details feels like leaky abstraction. Isn't an Anticorruption Layer precisely supposed to protect you from that?

If you consider that its the ACL's job to adapt from your world to the external system's world, then I'd say it's its job too to map from your IDs to their IDs, and only it should have access to the external IDs. How and where to store these IDs is a technical detail. Maybe it's more convenient to store them in the same DB table as your internal IDs. But I think they shouldn't be part of the Identity BC.

Comment: Well when a user registers on my application they also register the accounts they have on the external system, IDs and credentials. So I was treating the external IDs as part of my domain because it also serves the purpose of validating operations that can't be done across their external accounts.

Comment: I'm not sure why knowing external IDs is required for this. But it might be because I don't really get your last sentence, too :)

Comment: Appreciate your help, been stuck on this for some time. What I mean is that the user has Account A and B in the external system. You can move things around inside A or B,  but not from one to the other. So I need to differentiate them.

Comment: "You can move things" should be "the anticorruption layer can move things", IMO, not the other BCs. Also, a big picture schema of your system and the external system and how they work together could help.

Comment: So the use case is: User has account A and B in external system. User wants to use my application to automate and handle some actions for them on the external system. This is really the essence of my application. 

On my application the external actions are written as a domain service on my terms, and implemented as an ACL. For my ACL to be able to perform these actions it needs their account IDs and credentials. The IDs are part of my language because the external accounts are part of my language. They are kinda explicitly fundamental to my application...

Comment: ... The User needs to register those external accounts on their local account (on my context) so that I know about them and can include them in my logic and handle them for the user.


My doubt is how I should handle the credentials. They are currently part of the registration process because without those credentials my application would not do anything. The credentials are specific to each external account the user has. I need the user to provide me with them because there's not way for the application to get them on its own, so I've modeled it as part of the ExternalAccount object.

Comment: Is your Core Domain only about that? Only services, no entities, no ubiquitous language of its own, no business rules or invariants to enforce, no collaborative context? Is DDD such a good fit then? Is there a point in having an anticorruption layer when your domain layer seems to mimic that of the external system?

Comment: Yeah, my core domain really is heavily dependent on that external system. I'd say it's almost a consumer-supplier relationship that I turned ACL. I even applied some of Evans ideas about these kind of relationships from here http://dddcommunity.org/library/evans_2011_2/ and made it a synchronizing ACL. I'm starting to think that DDD is in fact overkill for this project. From the beginning it was supposed to be an exercise of writing good software and making it flexible, platform independent even. And I think I almost got it. Perhaps it won't fit 100% into the guidelines, but I can live with it

Comment: Just thought maybe there's a better way to deal specifically with credentials. Since this post I've realized the lack of complexity of the project and folded my contexts into 1. I think I'll have an app service with a method that will take an account ID and the inventories to handle. There I will query for the user and their credentials for the account and ask the external domain services to perform the actions through the ACL.

Comment: Still... I think the question is valid, even if my particular case is fuzzy. In a more complex application modeled with DDD how would one deal with credentials to external services? Facebook accounts, or Twitter, or anything else that has a public API that requires credentials for any operation.

Comment: It depends. If it's only about using a third party account system to log into your application, I'd say it can stay in the identity Bounded Context. For more elaborate actions such as "Publish this on Twitter" or "Friend that person on FB", you could either incorporate it as part of your main Ubiquitous Language, or give each operation a more generic name and have adapters and ACLs for each specific social media.

Comment: Regarding DDD being overkill here, I think the tactical patterns are, definitely. Strategic patterns like Bounded Context can still apply though (I have yet to see a system where it doesn't). My point was just that if your particular BC has an anemic domain model and one that is entirely dictated by the external system, ACL might not be the right choice because there is nothing to protect from "corruption".

Comment: Alright, for the friend that person on Facebook scenario: how would you write the method? friendOnFb(aFriendId, onFbAccountId, withFbCredentials) Would you include the credentials like that or no? Or maybe pass in a FacebookAccount object that contains the ID and credentials?

Comment: I don't think it makes that much of a difference. A better question would be : where do you get the Facebook account ID from ? Same for the Facebook credentials ? Does the main BC ask the Identity BC for Facebook IDs ? Does it store a local copy of Facebook account IDs and update it each time a `FacebookAccountAdded` event comes from the Identity BC ? Are the Facebook credentials one-time only, provided by the user at the moment of the action, or are they stored as well ?

Comment: That's kinda the whole point of the question... It's the same thing I explained just now we're talking in FB terms. Say the main BC is concerned with friends as well as what FB account to friend them on, so the main BC already has a concept of FB Acc ID, the question is where should I involve the credentials? Application service on Identity BC credentialsForFbAcc(anAccId) and use that from the ACL that implements the friendOnFb domain service? And the credentials are provided by user and stored until expired at which point user has to update them.